# Ordering images game

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I am trying to make a simple game in which I show five movie posters and the user has to order them by release date, like shown in the attached picture (these posters are random ones I found).

[image]

Each picture is coded like this:

```
<div id="div11" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" style="display:inline-block; position:relative">
        <img value="5" src="../images/movies/hobbit.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag15" width="162" height="240">
</div>
```

Where div11 means div1,image1, so the others will be like div12, div13...The image id drag15 means that this images is the fifth in the correct order, so the others are drag11, drag12...

And the div where they are going to be put is like this:

```
<div id="div21" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" style="display:inline-block; position:relative"></div>
```

So the image with the id="drag13", for example, has to be put in the div with id="div23". I have the following function to allow the dragging and dropping of the images in the blank divs, but when I drag an image to a div where there is already an image, the second one disappears:

```
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text",ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
```

Here you can find a jsfiddle to try and help you understand what I mean and what I have at the moment: http://jsfiddle.net/3GKPn/2/

Comment: It would be useful to help you out if you created a jsfiddle

Comment: I am not very familiar with jsfiddle and as you will see it is not working very well, but I think you can get an idea of what I have in terms of code (I am very new at this, I apologize if my mistakes are too obvious)

http://jsfiddle.net/3GKPn/

Comment: Since you use relative path, jsfiddle cannot find your images. I updated yours with dummy images. http://jsfiddle.net/3GKPn/1/ You can edit your post and add it so it will be easier for people to help you out.

Comment: Yous function `check()` will work if you use `node = document.getElementById( "drag1"+i );`

Comment: This is your updated jsfiddle answering your second question: http://jsfiddle.net/3GKPn/2/. You can update your question by removing this part and including this jsffidle.

Comment: Perfect! Now the check() function works just fine! Now the only problem is that when I drag, for example, image 1 to the div where image 4 is, image 1 completely disappears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the `ondrop` event handler, when dropping on an img (not a div), you use this code:

```
ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
```

That will append the dragged image to the target which is also an image. Hence the dragged image disappears. You have to check if the dropping target is an image or not, if it's an image, the natural behavior is swapping the 2 images. Here is the code it should be:

```
function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
    var dragged = document.getElementById(data);
    //check if the dropping target is an image
    if(ev.target.tagName == "IMG") {
      //preparing to swap the 2 images (the dragged image and the target image)
      var parent = ev.target.parentElement || ev.target.parentNode;
      dragged.parentElement.appendChild(ev.target);
      parent.appendChild(dragged);
    } else {
      //check if the div already has some img, 
      //swap the 2 images
      if(ev.target.children.length > 0) {
        dragged.parentElement.appendChild(ev.target.children[0]);
      }
      ev.target.appendChild(dragged);
    }
}
```

I've also modifying the CSS a little to make the images smaller for better rendering (and testing) right in jsFiddle.

### [Updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/3GKPn/5/).

Answer (score -1):

Try this fiddle : [DragAndDropModule](http://jsfiddle.net/GRDww/40/)

```
$(function() {
// there's the gallery and the transfer
var $gallery = $( "#gallery" ),
    $transfer = $( "#transfer" ),
    $gen_dialog = $( '#gen_dialog' );

// let the gallery items be draggable
$( "li", $gallery ).draggable({
    cancel: "a.ui-icon", // clicking an icon won't initiate dragging
    revert: "invalid", // when not dropped, the item will revert back to its initial position
    containment: "document",
    helper: "clone",
    cursor: "move"        
});

// let the transfer be droppable, accepting the gallery items
$transfer.droppable({
    accept: "#gallery > li",
    activeClass: "ui-state-highlight",
    drop: function( event, ui ) {
        deleteImage( ui.draggable );
    }
});

// let the gallery be droppable as well, accepting items from the transfer
$gallery.droppable({
    accept: "#transfer li",
    activeClass: "custom-state-active",
    drop: function( event, ui ) {
        recycleImage( ui.draggable );
    }
});

// set up the generate button's dialog box
$gen_dialog.dialog({
    autoOpen:false,
    height:140,
    'title': 'Generated Report',
    modal:true
});

// function for generating info of icon/s in drop box
$('button.generate').click(function() {
    var content = $('ul li h5', $transfer).map(function(i, v) {
        return $(this).text();
    }).get();
    $gen_dialog.find('.diag-content').html(content.join(', ')).end().dialog('open');
});
//function for resetting the icons back to original positions
$('button.reset').click(function() {
    $('ul li', $transfer).each(function() {
        recycleImage($(this));
    });
});

toggleButtons();

        // image deletion function
        var recycle_icon = "<a href='link/to/recycle/script/when/we/have/js/off' title='Transfer this icon back' class='ui-icon ui-icon-transfer-e-w'>Transfer this icon back</a>";
        function deleteImage( $item ) {
          $item.fadeOut(function() {
            var $list = $( "ul", $transfer ).length ?
              $( "ul", $transfer ) :
              $( "<ul class='gallery ui-helper-reset'/>" ).appendTo( $transfer );

            $item.find( "a.ui-icon-transferthick-e-w" ).remove();
            $item.append( recycle_icon ).appendTo( $list ).fadeIn(function() {
              $item
                .animate({ width: "48px" })
                .find( "img" )
              .animate({ height: "36px" }, function() {
            toggleButtons();
              });
            });
          });
        }

        // image recycle function
        var transfer_icon = "<a href='link/to/transfer/script/when/we/have/js/off' title='Transfer Across' class='ui-icon ui-icon-transferthick-e-w'>Transfer Across</a>";
        function recycleImage( $item ) {
          $item.fadeOut(function() {
            $item
              .find( "a.ui-icon-transfer-e-w" )
                .remove()
              .end()
              .css( "width", "96px")
              .append( transfer_icon )
              .find( "img" )
                .css( "height", "72px" )
              .end()
              .appendTo( $gallery )
            .fadeIn(function() {
            toggleButtons();
            });
          });
        }
// display buttons when icon transferred across     
function toggleButtons() {
    $('div.col3 button').toggle($('> ul > li', $transfer).length > 0);
}


        // resolve the icons behavior with event delegation
        $( "ul.gallery > li" ).click(function( event ) {
          var $item = $( this ),
            $target = $( event.target );

          if ( $target.is( "a.ui-icon-transferthick-e-w" ) ) {
            deleteImage( $item );
          } else if ( $target.is( "a.ui-icon-transfer-e-w" ) ) {
            recycleImage( $item );
          }

          return false;
        });
      });
```

Comment: OP is not including jQuery, evident from the code snippets posted and from the JSFiddle which does not include the library.

Comment: Thanks anyway, I will also try this! very much appreaciated, Eirenaios!

Comment: thank you for your support if you like my effort then please vote up! [who wants negative vote for an effort!] thanks anyways :)